# Javascript Confirm Button

Tags: javascript, confirm

My code is working.But when the confirm box shows up, i press the "ok" button and then i place the numbers and its working.But if i press the "cancel" button  place the numbers and then nothing happens.

```js
var responce;
var n1, n2, n3, n4, sum;
var m1, m2, mion;


responce = window.confirm("Click OK to add,\nClick Cancel to subtract");

if (responce) {
  function add(number1, number2, number3, number4) {
    sum = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4;
    document.write("Adding your numbers gives you the effect of:" + sum);
  }
  n1 = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a Number", "0"));
  n2 = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a second number", "0"));
  n3 = parseFloat(prompt("Give a third number", "0"));
  n4 = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a fourth number", "0"));

} else {
  function noadd(number5, number6) {
    mion = m1 - m2;
    document.write("Subtracting your numbers is the result that is:" + mion);
  }
  m1 = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a Number", "0"));
  m2 = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a second number", "0"));
}


add(n1, n2, n3, n4);


noadd(m1, m2);
```

Comment: `if i press the "cancel" button place the numbers and then nothing happens`What do you expect `cancel` to do?

Comment: when i will press the cancel button i will place 2 numbers (For example 50 and 20 ) and the function will do 50 - 20 = 30     My problem is that i place the numbers and nothing shows up

Comment: You're declaring functions based on condition, but then call them both so one of them has to be undeclared

Comment: Also do not use document.write - if you do that after the page has loaded, the page is wiped. Instead use innerText of some container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely want this

```js
var res, response;
var n1, n2, n3, n4, sum;
var m1, m2, mion;


function add(number1, number2, number3, number4) {    
  sum = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4;    
  res.innerHTML = "Adding your numbers gives you the effect of:" + sum;
}  
function noadd(number5, number6) {    
  mion = m1 - m2;    
  res.innerHTML = "Subtracting your numbers is the result that is: " + mion;
}


window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  res = document.getElementById("result");
  response = window.confirm("Click OK to add,\nClick Cancel to subtract");

  if (response) {  
    n1 = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a Number", "0"));  
    n2 = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a second number", "0"));  
    n3 = parseFloat(prompt("Give a third number", "0"));  
    n4 = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a fourth number", "0"));
    add(n1, n2, n3, n4);
  } else {  
    m1 = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a Number", "0"));  
    m2 = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a second number", "0"));
    noadd(m1, m2);
  }
  
})
```

```html
<span id="result"></span>
```